# Best way to make xml file editable on web

Tags: xml

I have a huge configuration file(xml based), which is frequently updated by the customer.
Now i don't want user to make configuration changes directly to the file as user may enter invalid data which can invalidate the file.
For now i have a form which takes inputs from user and then at server side i am using xpath to edit the xml.The UI experience is poor as you can enter multiple child tags to a parent and for each addition there's a postback to server and also it requires a lot of user inputs as to know where in the dom he wants to add the tags.
Is there any way i can represent my xml in html editable form and provide user with dropdowns to select values from and also he can add new tags. I am open to technologies, JS, php, .net , java or any client side library.

Comment: There's a project, [XmlGrid](http://xmlgrid.net/demo.html), that intend to work as an online xml editor using a tree based visualization. Had you tried it?

Comment: No i did'nt, i am checking if it works.Looks promising though.

Comment: @FlavioCysne, it is exactly what i was looking for. One thing i noticed was , when i am uploading my XML, it is editable but i cannot insert new Nodes whereas in case of building a new xml i can.Did you also notice the same or i am missing something?

Comment: What http://xmlgrid.net/ are doing is awesome, can't we extend it?I mean how are they doing it? Is it something to do with xslt to show xml as editable html form or there's some more magic to it?